# Merge partial (or entire) geographical paths

Tags: comparison

I have data of a vehicle route and some data already inserted in the system. I have to find the parts of the route that are already presents in the system in order to avoid duplicate the info.

The data is given in latitude-longitude format. The positions given are never the same.

What do you think is the best method to make a comparison and determine which parts of the routes are equal enough?

Maybe the next image helps:
[image]

[image]

In yellow the parts of the rowute that have been marked as "similar"

Comment: Can you please edit your question specifying the GIS software you are using?

Comment: I am not using any GIS Software. Indeed, another question could be about the best software to do that...